# ¿Porque no me puede enlazar los archivos objetos si todos los prototipo usados están definidos?

Tags: c++, enlace, g++

Estoy realizando un interprete golfscript, el problema que a la hora de compilar la app me sale un error que las funciones que llamo no están definidas, pero yo la defino y compilo en un archivo objeto y al final los compilo:

```
g++ -std=c++20 -Wall ./build/obj/main.o ./build/obj/str.o ./build/obj/stack.o ./build/obj/run.o -o ./GolfScript_pirata.exe 2> ./build/log/log_app.txt
```

Me sale este error:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ./build/obj/run.o:run.cpp:(.text+0x148): undefined reference to `Var::Var(TYPE, void*)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ./build/obj/run.o:run.cpp:(.text+0x476): undefined reference to `Var::interpret[abi:cxx11](std::vector<Var, std::allocator<Var> >&, std::vector<Var, std::allocator<Var> >&)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ./build/obj/run.o:run.cpp:(.text+0x548): undefined reference to `Var::Var(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, TYPE, void*)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ./build/obj/run.o:run.cpp:(.text+0x70f): undefined reference to `Var::interpret[abi:cxx11](std::vector<Var, std::allocator<Var> >&, std::vector<Var, std::allocator<Var> >&)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Y claramente en el archivo stack.cpp defino esas funciones:

```
class Var{
    /**
         * @brief Construct a new Var object
         * 
         * @param n Nombre de la variable
         * @param t Tipo de variable.
         * @param v Valor.
    */
    Var(string n, enum TYPE t, void *v)
    {
        var.name = n;
        setValue(t, v);
    }
    /**
     * @brief Construct a new Var object
     * 
     * @param t Tipo de dato
     * @param v el dato como tal.
     */
    Var(enum TYPE t, void *v)
    {
        var.type = t;
        var.value = v;
    }
    string interpret(vector<Var>& stack,vector<Var>& vars){
        switch (var.type)
        {
        case INT:
            stack.push_back(Var(INT,var.value));
            break;
        case FUNCTION: // Creo que en el lenguaje no existe, pero de todos modos lo voy a utilizar para los operadodes:)
            // No hay nada que liberar, pues solo estoy apuntando a una función no a una memoria dinamica.
            //Recuerda todas las funciónes deben tener estos dos argumentos:
            func(stack,vars);
            break;
        case STRING:
            stack.push_back( 
                Var(STRING,(void*)( *(string*)var.value).c_str())
            );
            break;
        case CODES_BLOCKS: // Será un string que representará el bloque de instrucciones.
            return (*(string*)var.value).substr(1,(*(string*)var.value).length());//Retornamos el bloque para que lo interprete.
        case ARRAY:        // Solo será un array, necesito crear una función que lea el string y retorne la posición.
            stack.push_back(
                Var(ARRAY,(void*)(*(string*)var.value).c_str())
            );
        } 
        return "";
    }
}
```

Y dentro del archivo run.cpp incluyo stack.h donde tengo todos los prototipo de stack.cpp:

```
Var(std::string n,enum TYPE t,void* v);
/**
 * @brief Construct a new Var object
 * @param t Tipo de dato
 * @param v el dato como tal.
 */
Var(enum TYPE t,void*v);
/**
 * @brief Aqui almacenamos la variable deacuerdo a su tipo de dato, y si ya está definida la liberamos para volverla a definir.
 * @param t El tipo que es la variable.
 * @param v valor de la variable.
**/
void setValue(enum TYPE t, void* v);
/**
 * @brief Función que ingresa el valor en la pila, o ejecuta una función en especifico.
 *
 * @param stack pila.
 * @param vars variables.
 * @return string -- Retorna una cadena vacia si
 */
string interpret(vector<Var>& stack,vector<Var>& vars);
```

No creo que sea como lo llamó desde el archivo run.cpp porque el ide no me alerta de ningún error(algo que siempre hace cuando llamo mal a una función).

[Aquí dejo todo mi códigos](https://github.com/dabl03/GolfScript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sospecho que el problema se debe a que estás haciendo el proceso justo al revés.

En los archivos **.h** deberían estar las declaraciones. O sea, este código en tu caso:

```
class Var{
    /**
         * @brief Construct a new Var object
         * 
         * @param n Nombre de la variable
         * @param t Tipo de variable.
         * @param v Valor.
    */
    Var(string n, enum TYPE t, void *v);

    /**
     * @brief Construct a new Var object
     * 
     * @param t Tipo de dato
     * @param v el dato como tal.
     */
    Var(enum TYPE t, void *v);

    string interpret(vector<Var>& stack,vector<Var>& vars);
}
```

Mientras que en archivo **.cpp** las implementaciones, agregando el nombre de la clase seguido de cuatro puntos antes del nombre de la función:

```
Var::Var(string n, enum TYPE t, void *v)
{
    var.name = n;
    setValue(t, v);
}

Var::Var(enum TYPE t, void *v)
{
    var.type = t;
    var.value = v;
}

string Var::interpret(vector<Var>& stack,vector<Var>& vars){
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, lo que hice en el archivo stack cpp fue declarar la clase como se haria normalmente: string interpret(...){....}